# Запись json в куки

Tags: json, javascript, cookie

Добрый день, получаю данные с сервера в виде json:

> ```
> {
> {"id":"1","parent_id":"0","lever":"0","name":"text"},{"id":"2","parent_id":"0","lever":"0","name":"text"},{"id":"3","parent_id":"0","lever":"0","name":"text"},
> ...
> }
> ```

пытаюсь сохранить в куке так:

```
data - это ответ с вервера
document.cookie = "cook_name=" + data + "; expires=" + (new Date(Date.now() + 7 * 86400000).toGMTString());
```

результат такой:

```
[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],
```

делаю так:

```
document.cookie = "cook_name=" + JSON.stringify(data) + "; expires=" + (new Date(Date.now() + 7 * 86400000).toGMTString());
```

и так:

```
document.cookie = "cook_name=" + escape(JSON.stringify(data)) + "; expires=" + (new Date(Date.now() + 7 * 86400000).toGMTString());
```

никак не сохраняет. Как можно сохранить? Подскажите.

Answer (score 1):

```
var array = [
    {'key1':'value1'},
    {'key2':'value2'},
    {'key3':'value3'}
];

document.cookie = "cook_name=" + JSON.stringify(array) + "; expires=" + (new Date(Date.now() + 7 * 86400000).toGMTString());
```

Учтите, работает только на домене. По крайней мере в лисе.